# Preg_match_all() put results in associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

So as the title says is there anyway to make this:

```
$leagueoflegendswebsite = file_get_contents($_POST['leagueoflegendswebsite']);

preg_match_all('/{{ci\|([^\|||}]+)/', $leagueoflegendschampions, $champion);
```

`$leagueoflegendschampions` is just a part of the `$leagueoflegendswebsite`.

`var_dump()`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUgZp.png

Is there any way to make it like `$champion['Sona']`, `$champion['Blitzcrank']`, `$champion['Fiddlestick']` and so on?

Comment: Would be better to paste in the text of the `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your matches array, use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$champion = array_combine($champion[1], $champion[0]);
```

Or to have default values, fill the keys:

```
$champion = array_fill_keys($champion[1], ''); // or use some value other than ''
```

Or flip it:

```
$champion = array_flip($champion[1]);
```

Comment: well then it gives me something like 'Sona' => string '{{ci|Sona' (length=9) I don't really care about the {{ci|Sona part. Right now I just want to have associative array (empty) with only names of keys in that array so $Champion['Sona'] $Champion['whatever'] and I'll add values after that